# Ajax json request fails with no error information

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-services

I am trying to make a simple HelloWorld Request with ajax json.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://easystoremanager.com/MyWebService/FlashService.asmx/HelloWorld",
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "json",
                // data: '',
                success: function (data) {
                    // do something with server response data
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    // handle your error logic here
                    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                }
            });
```

Hello World mark up looks like this

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld() {
    return "Hello";
}
```

When making my ajax request the alert says

> "Error: error" "Error:  "

Any idea how to capture an actual error or see whats wrong?

**WEB.CONFIG Changes**

```
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you're telling jQuery to expect a JSON result (`datatype: "json",`) and you're not telling your service to return JSON (`[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json]`)

Comment: @Stryner I added [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)] above HelloWorld() but I still get the same result

Comment: Please set `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` in order to trace the error.

Comment: @Hackerman I set it off

Comment: I have made some changes to the web.config. I not get an internal server error 500. I believe its because its cross domain? Anyone know what I need to tweak in IIS or web.config?

Comment: @Lucky yes same internal error 500. If I run the request on the server it works fine. As soon as I do it remotely it erros